# What is the default parameter for a Command binding in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="abc" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

while `MyCommand` is an ICommand property. The command is getting invoked without any problems, but the parameter is always `null`.

Is that intended as a default or have I done something wrong with setting up the `DataContext`?
If I have done something wrong, what should the argument be?

- I know the parameter is null from the debugger, and because my commands code is `(p) => { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(p?.ToString() ?? "p is null"); }`, which always shows a messagebox with "p is null".

Comment: just for test before everything else try a stable string like `string test = " example text ";` and use it in your Binding , if it show up .. then the problem will be in your `p` string variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use parameters you have to add `CommandParameter="..."` in your xaml. But you don't have to if you just want to use your command without parameters like you did; they are optional.

Comment: I would just add that some Command Bindings will pass a default value such as EventTriggers can pass in the eventArgs

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a place where I can lookup which commands do have a default parameter?